# AWS S3 - key is not expected for the get method

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, evaporate.js

Very weird occurrence of this error (see below). Points of note:

- Web app in question has >500 daily users, all of them uploading objects into S3 daily
- Two users, have this one error when they try and upload a file
- The same users, if they try a different computer, do not get this error
- Web app is using the EvaporateJS library - https://github.com/TTLabs/EvaporateJS
- There seems to be no pattern with regards to file size (even a tiny <10kb file will cause it)
- The authentication/authorisation component of the web app is handled by the web-app. I.e. - The IAM user associated with generating the S3 upload Url is shared for all web app users, so I have ruled out a permission issue for the IAM user ID in question

Error message:

```
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
  <Message>
    Key is not expected for the GET method ?uploads subresource
  </Message>
  <RequestId>
    *****
  </RequestId>
  <HostId>
    *****
  </HostId>
</Error>
```

From all the points above, the only variable here seems to be the computers. Am I right? Have I overlooked something? If it is the computers, any idea what would be the issue there? An overactive firewall/something else preventing the upload network requests?

Thanks in advance for any guidance in decipher this error message (what does it even mean?!)

Comment: I will suggest you check the Browser version,  extension installed.  Also you can install other Chromium based browser and try them out.

Comment: Enable [logging for your bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html).  The `<RequestId>` in the error message corresponds to the 6th column in the logs.  This appears to be a problem with your code making an invalid (nonsensical) request and a second problem of that request actually being authorized, which may have security implications.  Finding the bucket log entry is a first step.

Comment: @mootmoot - I tested for this variable by wrapping everything in an Electron environment. Same scenario - worked on some computers, but not on these computers. And Electron means that there are no other extensions running.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Cheers for the suggestions, I'll go ahead and give that a shot to see if it helps shed light. I'm still bamboozled by the fact that 99% of clients (all running the same exact code), have no issues at all.